# Unable to use aligned `operator new` in a module with Clang

Tags: c++, clang, c++20, c++-modules

I'm experimenting with Clang "modules" feature, and I'm trying to compile following piece of code:

```
export module a;

#include <new>

export void *foo()
{
    return ::operator new(1, std::align_val_t(1));
}

export int main() {}
```

<kbd>[Try it live](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'export+module+a%3B%0A%0A%23include+%3Cnew%3E%0A%0Aexport+void+*foo()%0A%7B%0A++++return+::operator+new(1,+std::align_val_t(1))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport+int+main()+%7B%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50.50746268656716,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang800,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a+-pedantic-errors+-fmodules-ts+--precompile+-x+c%2B%2B-module',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+8.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:25.335588551489735,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+8.0.0',t:'0')),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:49.49253731343284,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)</kbd>

When I tried `clang++ -std=c++2a -pedantic-errors -fmodules-ts --precompile -x c++-module a.cpp -o a.pcm`, I got

> ```
> error: ISO C++ requires a definition in this translation unit for function 'operator new'
>  because its type does not have linkage [-Werror,-Wundefined-internal-type]
> a.cpp:7:14: note: used here
>     return ::operator new(1, std::align_val_t(1));
>          ^
> 1 error generated.
> ```

Removing `-pedantic-errors` fixes the error, but when I try to link the resulting module using `clang++ -std=c++2a -fmodules-ts a.pcm -o a.exe`, I get

> ```
> Z:\Lander\msys2\tmp\a-cfaf65.o:a.pcm:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to
>  `_ZnwyW1aESt11align_val_t'
> clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

It's especially annoying since `<iostream>` (indirectly) seems to rely on the aligned `operator new`, so I can't use it in modules too. As well as some other standard headers.

What's going on here?

It it's a Clang bug, how can I work around it?

---

My Clang is the latest version provided by MSYS2:

```
# clang++ --version
clang version 8.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_800/final)
Target: x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

---

**EDIT:**

Filed [a bug report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41364), let's see what happens...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard library isn't part of your module `a`. So don't include the header after the `export module a;`. Include the header before that.

Comment: Huh. Got it, thanks! But do you happen to know what the error means exactly? Aligned new is declared as `void* operator new(std::size_t, std::align_val_t) __attribute__((__externally_visible__));` for me, so it should have external linkage, rather than no linkage?